# How to get the VLAN ID in snort alert?

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection, vlan

I am trying to parse snort alerts and filter necessary information such as vlan id where a malicious internal machine belong to! 
However, I only can get the message, source and destination IPs, I need to get the VLAN ID too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*(Assuming you're using Unified2 log format)*

You can get the VLAN ID logged by using the `vlan_event_types` parameter when specifying the alert configuration:

```
output alert_unified2: \
    filename <base filename> [, <limit <size in MB>] [, nostamp] [, mpls_event_types] \
    [, vlan_event_types]
```

When enabled and the packet contains a VLAN header, a log item will contain the following record with `vlan id`:

> E. Unified2 IDS Event (Version 2)
>
> ```
> sensor id               4 bytes
> event id                4 bytes
> event second            4 bytes
> event microsecond       4 bytes
> signature id            4 bytes
> generator id            4 bytes
> signature revision      4 bytes
> classification id       4 bytes
> priority id             4 bytes
> ip source               4 bytes
> ip destination          4 bytes
> source port/icmp type   2 bytes
> dest. port/icmp code    2 bytes
> protocol                1 byte
> impact flag             1 byte
> impact                  1 byte
> blocked                 1 byte
> mpls label              4 bytes
> vlan id                 2 bytes
> padding                 2 bytes
> ```
>
> Unified2 IDS Event (Version 2) are logged for IPv4 packets which
>   contain either MPLS or VLAN headers. Otherwise a Unified2 IDS Event is
>   logged.
>
> - Note that you’ll need to pass –enable-mpls to configure in order to
>     have Snort fill in the mpls label field.
> - Note that you’ll need to configure unified2 logging with either
>     mpls_event_types or vlan_event_types to get this record type.
>
> [https://www.snort.org/faq/readme-unified2]